# Можно ли деплоить Docker-приложение на VPS без Docker Hub и сторонних сервисов?

Tags: docker

На момент задавания этого вопроса я получил начальные навыки по инициализации Docker-проекта и работы с образами и контейнерами, однако в процессе деплоя Docker-приложения не понимаю пока практически ничего.

В тех обучающих курсах, которые я видел, говорилось о деплое-приложения с помощью Docker Hub или сторонних серверов как само собой разумеющемся способе. Подозрения вызывает то, что ничего не было сказано о таком способе, как деплой напрямую себе на VPS с помощью FTP. Если пошагово, то этот гипотетический способ таков:

1. Собираем образ у себя на компьютере
2. Загружаем его на VPS через FTP(S)
3. Запускаем там контейнер

Возможно, у Вас будет вопрос, чем меня не устраивает загрузка проекта через Docker Hub. Дело в том, что мы добавляем в процесс создания и сопровождения приложения дополнительных посредников, а верее их облачное хранилище - Docker-овское или нет. Если это какой-нибудь учебно-тренировочный или маловажный проект, то нет проблем, а что если это какое-нибудь важное приложение, работающее с секретными данными, да ещё и не своё, а заказанное какой-нибудь крупной компанией? Получается, что используя Docker Hub или GitHub, мы добровольно предоставляем им образ, а зачастую и исходный код своего приложения. Поэтому должен быть какой-то способ, когда между локальным компьютером и VPS посредников нет - просто берём Docker-образ и загружаем его себе на VPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker save` - выгружает созданный образ в `tar`

`docker load` - делает обратную операцию

После выгрузки в `tar`, его множно сжать, и отправить, как вы хотите, по `FTP` на сервер.

Но лучше будет отправить старичка `FTP` на пенсию, и, *не сжимая файл*, воспользоваться `rsync` - так, при многократной досылке одного и того же обновляемого файла, `rsync` будет передавать только разницу между старым и новым, а сжатие можно включить уже в нем.

[Многабукав](https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2019/docker-import-export-vs-load-save/) по теме

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! И особенно за `rsyns` - я давно думал, как добиться такого эффекта без системы контроля версий (СКВ нужна в основном для исходного кода, а не для того, что деплоится).

Comment: "а сжатие можно включить уже в нем" - подскажите пожалуйста, а это как и зачем? В случае с FTP я понял, что сжатие нужно чтобы пересылаемый файл был меньше, но с RSync ситуация другая, так? Может быть Вы имеете ввиду, что RSync может сжимать данный перед отправкой и восстанавливать их при получении?

Comment: @БоковГлеб - ну да, я это и имею в виду.

Comment: Очень здорово, что есть такая функция!